# Does Haxe have a friendship with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, haxe

I need to get some XML node by it's XPath, how I can do it?

I tried to use this library https://github.com/djcsdy/haxe-xpath, but something wrong https://github.com/djcsdy/haxe-xpath/issues/26

and for my task xml-fast isn't good solution, because it looks "slightly worse" than XPath, I think:

js (xpath):

```
xml_doc.get('//project/classpaths/class[@path="' + src_path + '"]')
```

haxe (xml-fast):

```
(new Fast(xml_doc))).node.project.node.classpaths.nodes.class.filter(function (x:Fast) return x.has.path ? x.att.path == src_path : false)
```

thanks

Comment: for library "haxe-xpath" was made some little fixes https://github.com/djcsdy/haxe-xpath/issues/26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As result was found two libraries and both require some fixes.

**1.** ["Haxe XPath"](https://github.com/djcsdy/haxe-xpath)

it can be used only if clone directory "haxe-xpath/src/xpath" into you sources (haxelib repo isn't contains this library).

Some fixes was needed for this library: [this](https://github.com/djcsdy/haxe-xpath/issues/26) and [this](https://github.com/djcsdy/haxe-xpath/issues/28)

**example** (delete first found element):

```
package;

import xpath.XPathHx;
using Lambda;

class Main {
    public static function main () {
        var xml = Xml.parse("<a> <b> <c>qwe</c> <c>asd</c> </b> </a>");
        trace(xml.toString());

        var xpExpr = new XPathHx("//a/b/c"); // create new XPath expression object
        var result = xpExpr.selectNodes(xml).array()[0]; // get first element from array of founded xml-nodes

        result.parent.removeChild(result); // remove selected node from xml-tree
        trace(xml.toString());
    }
}
```

---

**2.** ["xmlTools"](https://github.com/TomByrne/xml-tools)

it can be installed with haxelib:

```
haxelib install xmlTools
haxelib install composure
```

[Some fix was needed for this library (in my task)](https://github.com/TomByrne/xml-tools/issues/2) and one [nuance for xpath](https://github.com/TomByrne/xml-tools/issues/3).

**example** (delete first found element):

```
package;

import xmlTools.XPath;
using Lambda;

class Main {
    public static function main () {
        var xml = Xml.parse("<a> <b> <c>qwe</c> <c>asd</c> </b> </a>");
        trace(xml.toString());

        var xpath  = new XPath(); // create new XPath expression object
        var result = xpath.resolve(xml, "*/a/b/c").array()[0]; // get first element from array of founded xml-nodes

        result.parent.removeChild(result); // remove selected node from xml-tree        
        trace(xml.toString());
    }
}
```